# Verification of proof that $f(x) = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$ is bijective over the reals

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-verification

We consider $ f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{x-a}{b-a} $ for $f: \textbf{R} \rightarrow \textbf{R} $ where $a,b$ are both constants such that $a,b \in \textbf{R} $ and $b-a \neq 0$.

Proof that $ f$ is injective:  Suppose $ f(i) = f(j) $.  Then $ \displaystyle \frac{i-a}{b-a} = \frac{j-a}{b-a} $.  If we multiply both sides by $ b-a $ and then add $ a$ to both sides we obtain $ i=j $.  Thus $ f $ is injective.

Proof that $ f$ is surjective:  Take some $ m \in R $.  Let $ m=\displaystyle \frac{k-a}{b-a} $.  Multiply both sides by $ b-a $ and then add $ a$ to them to obtain $ k = (b-a)m+a $.  Thus $ f(k)=m $.  So $ f$ is surjective.

Since $f$ is both injective and surjective, $f$ is bijective.

Is this the correct way to prove bijectivity?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of injectivity is perfect. I would approach surjectivity slightly differently. Take some $m\in\Bbb R,$ and then let $k=(b-a)m+a.$ Then $k\in\Bbb R,$ and you can show that $f(k)=m.$

"Let $m=\frac{k-a}{b-a}$" basically assumes what you're trying to prove, though you'll certainly want to start there with your calculations.

As an alternate approach, let $m=\frac1{b-a}$ and $c=\frac{-a}{b-a},$ so that $f(x)=mx+c.$ That makes it slightly easier to prove bijectivity.

Comment: So I find $k$ through the method I employed, note that $k\in \textbf{R} $, and plug it in to $f$ to show that $f(k)=m$.  Basically, I do what I did except in reverse order.  Thanks!